# Windows Phone templates missing if switching from original english version to german language pack

Tags: templates, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, language-packs

I installed the english version of Visual Studio 2013 Professional and added the german language pack. If I switch the culture of Visual Studio 2013 from english to german, the templates for all Windows Phone specific project types are missing. I think, this happens, because the according resource-subfolders (%InstallPath%\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Phone\XXXX respectively %InstallPath%\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Phone\XXXX) exist only for the original english culture (subfolder 1033) and not for the german language pack (subfolder 1031)).

If I copy the 1033 - subfolders to 1031 - subfolders, I can see the english project templates in the german version, but selecting one of these items leads to an loading error. I think some linked resources are missing. Can anyone help me with this issue or do I have to wait for an according update from Microsoft ?